# Angularjs app doesn't render well on slow internet connection

Tags: angularjs

I got excited over the prospects of AngularJS. So I started learning it right away. However, to my dismay, AngularJS doesn't render content well on slow internet connections as you can see from the screenshots.

My Flask App basically displays my Linux machines details. I do this by running an ajax call to the server-side code and return json which I then display to the browser using Angular.

Is this a known problem with the framework or is it the way am writing my code. I call Angularjs at the footer as rendered by many users.

[image: AngularJS App render before completely loading]
[image: AngularJS App render after completely loading]

Here's a skeleton structure of my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <title>My flask app</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css') }}">

    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">

    <!-- custom-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="flaskApp">

    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="logo">Flask App</h1>
        <strong><nav>
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav></strong>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>

  <!-- Jquery JS-->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}}"></script>

   <!-- Angular JS-->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/angular.js')}}"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>

  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <!--  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/admin.js')}}"></script> -->
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/cmd.js')}}"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [ngClock](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) directive. It is used to prevent Angular from displaying uncompiled templates.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

and include de `ng-cloak` directive where you want. I usually put it in the `body` tag.

Comment: Works great,thanks. Am hoping this is something the framework should take care of in the future releases.

Comment: You are welcome, if it helped, mark it as the answer!